# Getting a 500 error when using cffileupload on a simple page

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion

When I try to use `cffileupload` on a simple ColdFusion page I get a 500 error. I am learning about ColdFusion as I go. Here is the code that I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <cffileupload  url="uploadFiles.cfm" progressbar="true" name="myupload" 
     addButtonLabel = "Add File" clearButtonlabel = "Clear it" 
     hideUploadButton = "true" width=600 height=400
     title = "File Upload" maxuploadsize="30" 
     extensionfilter="*.jpg, *.png, *.flv, *.txt" 
     BGCOLOR="##FFFFFF" MAXFILESELECT=10 UPLOADBUTTONLABEL="Upload now"/>
</body>
```

Am I missing something or is the hosting provider not allowing the `cffileupload` tag?

Comment: go to the coldfusion administrator and check the logs. it will tell you what went wrong.

Comment: I did log-in into admin and checked the logs, there was nothing, I had to remote log-in to windows and view error locally. Thanks